# Blender 3.0 fluid simulation not working right for me

Tags: mesh, fluid-simulation

As you will see in the image I attached, I have all the settings right (as far as I know) under my domain liquid. Even so, I am still stuck with just particles/spheres and no actual liquid. I've been stuck for days now. I need help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: My Blender version is 3.1.2 btw not 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My domain was set to *Bounds* under *Viewport Display*. Just had to change that.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but it looks like your domain size is razor thin on the z axis. it may be that the meshing isnt working because of this.  try making the domain size larger in 3d space and apply the scale and re bake.

Comment: Wrong. That's from the animation of the fluid but the domain is a lot bigger with the plane inside it. As you can see by the timeline, I wasn't on the first frame. Thanks for the reply tho